# Inconsistent dates formatting (lubridate fail)

Tags: r, date, formatting, lapply, lubridate

I have a vector of inconsistent dates, including (mainly) these three formats:
"%d/%m/%y", "%m/%d/%y" and "%d/%m/%Y"

I tried to implement this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("30/12/00","7/31/09","17/09/2008"),col.names = "original_date")

guess_date <- function(x){
  require(lubridate)
  guess <- guess_formats(x, c("mdy","dmy"))
  date <- as.Date(x, guess)[1]
  return(date)
}

df$date <- lapply(df$original_date, guess_date)
```

Comment: You seem to only be passing "mdy" to guess_formats when you seem to have data in "dmy" format. But what are you doing to do with dates like "11/12/2000"? If dates can start with either month or date it's not clear how that should be interpreted. What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass it with `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(df$original_date, 
    guess_formats(as.character(df$original_date), c("mdy", "dmy", "dmY")))
#[1] "2000-12-30 UTC" "2009-07-31 UTC" "2008-09-17 UTC"
```

Comment: I figured adding c("mdy","dmy") enabled the reading of European dates.
Still lapply does not work

Comment: @MCS IN your function, you are passing the formats into `as.Date` while the guess formats return the format in a slightly different way than the `as.Date` expects.  e.g. `guess_formats(as.character(df$original_date), c("mdy", "dmy"))#
       Omdy        dOmy        dOmy         mdy         dmy         dmy 
"%Om/%d/%y" "%d/%Om/%y" "%d/%Om/%Y"  "%m/%d/%y"  "%d/%m/%y"  "%d/%m/%Y" ` Note the change in format